# How we increase Recyler View Item from 0-9 to Infinite?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: I am using Recyler and Want to increase num to infinite]

My Code is:

```
  JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                        if(jsonArray.length()==0){
                            Toast.makeText(context,"No Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                innerListData = new TakeAttendanceModel();
                                innerListData = ((TakeAttendanceModel) JSonUtil.jsonToObject(jsonArray.getString(i), TakeAttendanceModel.class));
                                innerListData.status = "P";
                                innerListData.attendanceDate = DateTimeUtils.getDate();
                                attenList.add(innerListData);
                            }
                            submitAtten=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.takeAttendanceSubmit);
                            submitAtten.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                            Log.d("Responsse : ", response);

                    }
                    takeAttendanceAdapter = new TakeAttendanceAdapter(context,attenList);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                    recyclerViewAttendanceList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                    recyclerViewAttendanceList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerViewAttendanceList.setAdapter(takeAttendanceAdapter);
                    takeAttendanceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My Adapter code is:

```
 private List<TakeAttendanceModel> list;

    public TakeAttendanceAdapter(Context context, List<TakeAttendanceModel> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

    }
    @Override
    public AttendanceListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View convertview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.inner_list_attendance, parent, false);

        return new AttendanceListViewHolder(convertview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AttendanceListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.textViewStudentName.setText(list.get(position).studFullName);
        holder.textViewStudentRollNumber.setText(list.get(position).primaryKey);
        holder.texViewStudentPreFix.setText(list.get(position).prefix);


        holder.SSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                //final LinkedList<String> innerLinklist=new LinkedList<>();
                if (isChecked) {
                    /*innerLinklist.add(list.get(position).primaryKey);
                    innerLinklist.add(list.get(position).studFullName);
                    innerLinklist.add(list.get(position).status="P");*/
                    // linkedList.add(innerLinklist);
                    //Log.v("Attndce Liist After Toggle",linkedList.toString());
                    list.get(position).status="P";
                } else {
                    /*innerLinklist.add(list.get(position).primaryKey);
                    innerLinklist.add(list.get(position).studFullName);
                    innerLinklist.add(list.get(position).status="A");*/
                    // linkedList.add(innerLinklist);
                    //Log.v("Attndce Liist After Toggle",linkedList.toString());
                    list.get(position).status="A";
                }

                Log.v("Attndce Inner",list.toString());
                //DataManager.factory().linkedList.add(innerLinklist);


                //Log.v("Attndce Full Linklist",DataManager.factory().linkedList.toString());
            }

        });

        //Log.v("Attndce Liist After Toggle",DataManager.factory().linkedList.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class AttendanceListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        /*public ImageView imageViewProfilePic;*/
        public TextView textViewStudentName, textViewStudentRollNumber,texViewStudentPreFix;
        public SwitchCompat SSwitch;
        public AttendanceListViewHolder(View convertview) {
            super(convertview);
            texViewStudentPreFix=(TextView)convertview.findViewById(R.id.textAttendanceStudentPrfix) ;
            textViewStudentName = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttendanceStudentName);
            textViewStudentRollNumber = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttendanceStudentRollno);
            SSwitch = (SwitchCompat) convertview.findViewById(R.id.textViewAttendanceSwitch);
        }
    }
```

This is My adapter code in which switch is placed.

Actually in RecylerView I place a Switch button and when switch button is on at 0 position then Automatically switch is ON after 9th position.

Please give me a solution.

Comment: Please add your code you tried.

Comment: Where is your adapter code?

Comment: http://blog.inapptext.com/recyclerview-creating-dynamic-lists-and-grids-in-android-1/#responding_user_actions - use this blog as a reference to control user actions on recycler view

Comment: Please see adapter code #Mohammed Atif

Answer (score 0):

First things first, make a proper POJO class for your adapter.

never use something like `list.get(position).variable` instead of this make your variable as private and use setters and getters like `list.get(position).getVariable()` or `list.get(position).setVariable(variable)`

Then as you know, since RecyclerView always recycle the views, its advisable to use if followed by else for every UI change. In your case you are just changing the switch condition without resetting it anywhere.

> And the most important part, never use the position that is passed as
>   a paremeter. Instead use the adapter position as I specified in the
>   solution

Check the updated code below:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AttendanceListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        holder.textViewStudentName.setText(list.get(adapterPosition).studFullName);
        holder.textViewStudentRollNumber.setText(list.get(adapterPosition).primaryKey);
        holder.texViewStudentPreFix.setText(list.get(adapterPosition).prefix);
        holder.SSwitch.setSelected(list.get(adapterPosition).getStatus());

        holder.SSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                list.get(adapterPosition).setStatus(isChecked);
                notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition);
                Log.v("Attndce Inner",list.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: getStatus() is showing error @can not resolve method

Comment: i make getter setter but when we click on button then it still remain same position ON/OFF and after 9th position it change

Comment: and when we click 2nd time then it make an change in button ON/OFF

Comment: @rishabh i think you ddnt implement it properly, can you update your Javabean class and your updated adatper code too?

Comment: Please share your updated code. You are definitely not implementing it properly

Comment: Please see update code. when I press button it does not change in first click

Comment: Try replacing notifyItemChanged() with notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Placed but now button is not clicked and when we click 3-4 time then Ramadamly any button is click

Answer (score 0):

Update code is:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AttendanceListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        holder.textViewStudentName.setText(list.get(adapterPosition).studFullName);
        holder.textViewStudentRollNumber.setText(list.get(adapterPosition).primaryKey);
        holder.texViewStudentPreFix.setText(list.get(adapterPosition).prefix);
        holder.SSwitch.setSelected(list.get(adapterPosition).getStatus());



        holder.SSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {

                list.get(adapterPosition).setStatus(isChecked);
                notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition);
                Log.v("Attndce Inner",list.toString());


                //Log.v("Attndce Full Linklist",DataManager.factory().linkedList.toString());
            }

        });
```

Model Class is:

```
public class TakeAttendanceModel {
    public String primaryKey;
    public String prefix;
    public String studFullName;
    public String attendanceDate;
    public boolean status;

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
```